# How do I make an automated data pipeline in Databricks that pulls data once per month?

Tags: databricks, pipeline

I want to pull data from many data sources into databricks once per month but not sure how to do this in Databricks. I found this tool in databricks called Delta Live Tables: https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/index.html it seems like this is what I should use to create an automated data pipeline but I dont know how I can have this run automatically once per month. Does anyone know how to automate/schedule this process?

This is only within the Databricks portal, I cannot use it in Azure.

Thank you

Googled: schedule jobs in Databricks, Scheduling Delta Live Tables, ETL process in Databricks.

Comment: The top result for your first google search term is this: https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: What does "only within the Databricks portal, I cannot use it in Azure." mean?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks, I dont have access to Azure, I think there is a databricks option in Azure. So if I use "Schedule a job" does that mean I can write a cron in there and that will run throughout the rest of next year without me having to touch the pipeline again?

Comment: I have not used delta live tables, but we have several notebook which we schedule...Please refer to link for pipeline schedule https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-ui.html#schedule-a-pipeline and another link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/schedule-notebook-jobs for scheduling notebooks

Comment: Please note that Databricks is a service that can be used on top of all the three major cloud providers including AWS, Azure and GCP. There are other ways of triggering Databricks jobs too including CLI, API, Azure Data Factory etc. etc..

Comment: If you "dont have access to Azure" how are you doing any databricks development? (I'm assuming you are using the Azure flavour) Are you saying you need to trigger a job from some other platform? In that case you should be able to use the REST API but you will definitely need to authenticate in some way.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks. What I am saying is I know that Azure has there own Databricks component. I am simply using their website to do the pipeline. I dont need an event to trigger it, I simply need to set a scheduled time for when to ingest data. I think just creating a couple of notebooks timed one hour after each other should work,  please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: _simply using their website to do the pipeline_ who's website? Can you post a piece of the URL that you are using? It's really not clear what the actual constraint is here.